# How do I replay the tutorial in Splatoon 2?

Tags: splatoon-2

Recently I had a friend who wanted to try my copy of Splatoon 2. This was their first time playing and they were having trouble learning how to play.

Is it possible to replay the opening tutorial? Or would I need to create a new user profile?

Comment: For the sake of offering all possible solutions, you could just delete your save file to get the tutorial again. If it is anywhere I would guess maybe on the options screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the easiest way for somebody new to your Switch system and to Splatoon 2 to experience the tutorial is to create a new user for them. A new user will have his own save when starting splatoon 2 and thus should encounter the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

[As Crovaxon mentioned](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/316168/181240), outside of deleting your save file, the only way to replay the tutorial is to create a new user. This new user will have their own separate save file when starting Splatoon 2.

> #### How to add a new user to your Nintendo Switch
>
> 1. Head to **Settings** in the bottom menu of your Switch Home Screen
> 2. Navigate down to **Users** and select **Add User**
>
>    [image]
> 3. **Select an icon**, or click **More Options** if you want to make your own avatar.
>
>    [image]
> 4. Use the keyboard to choose a name for your account.
>
>    [image]
> 5. Confirm the avatar is set up the way you want and select **OK**.
>
>    [image]
> 6. Choose between adding a Nintendo Online account to your new account or select **Later**
>
>    [image]
> 7. Launch **Splatoon 2**, then select your newly created user profile.
>
> ***Adapted from [iMore: How to add a new user to your Nintendo Switch](https://www.imore.com/how-add-new-user-your-nintendo-switch)***